# Parsing API Data and using it at multiple places react

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am new to react and worked mostly in Java. So I was building a multipage application where I am showing the **same** data in multiple pages in different formats. So I just need the raw json data which I get from API **once** in a separate class and I want to reuse it in multiple places. I am stuck at this because all the tutorials I saw are passing in as rendered components which I do not have any to render as the class is just for getting API data. Maybe I am looking at it in wrong way. If anyone can help, here are my two classes for now:

In the class where I am getting the data:

```
var apidata = [];

export default class GetData extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    axios.get("https:...")
        .then(response => {
            response.data.map(eachObject => {
                apidata.push(eachObject);
                // console.log(eachObject);
            })
        });
}


render() {
    return (
        // Dont know what to return here
        {/*<App data={this.state}/>*/}
    );
}

}
```

In the class where I want to use the data:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this.state.data);
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({data : GetData.apiData});
}

componentDidMount() {
}

state = {data: []};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={margin_top}>
                <table className="table table-dark">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Department</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.data.map(eachObject =>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{count++}</th>
                            <td>{eachObject.department}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at some state management libraries like redux https://redux.js.org/ or you can use react context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse your API data services in multiple components.

just return your data service, your data service should return promise like below :

```
GetData.js

export function data() {
   return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
       .then(res => res.data) 
}
```

and then in your component,

```
import {data} from './GetData';

componentDidMount() {
    data().then(data=>{ 
      this.setState({
        persons: data
      })
   });
}
```

or export Data Fetch Call component like this :

```
export default class DataLoader extends Component {
  state = { data: [] };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState(() => {
          return { data };
        })
      );
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.render(this.state.data);
  }
}
```

and  in your component use it like below:

```
 <DataLoader
  render={data => {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {data.map(el => (
            <li key={el.id}>{el.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }}
/>
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qhrfhu)
 Used react context, use if you need

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you ! Just one follow up, whenever I  

`import {data} from './GetData';`

is react using the same data, or making a new call everytime ?

Answer (score 0):

Fetching GetData.apiData won't help, as the variable populated asynchronously

```
this.setState({data : GetData.apiData});
```

So, the good option is to use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

> React will efficiently update and render just the right components when your data changes. (in your case apiData)

https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist this will help you out

Comment: Yes, it seem ssl certification error on the link. Lets see this example https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos .This is a simple TODO repo using redux.js

Comment: Thanks. I have got that covered !